# modelsummary/kableExtra regression table with models of the same name

Tags: r, kableextra, modelsummary

I use `modelsummary()` with `kableExtra()` to generate a regression table in an Rmd file (final output format: LaTex and HTML).

I run regressions for several variable combinations and model specifications.
The regressions are grouped in the table by variable combinations via `kable::add_header_above()`.

For different variable combinations, I run the same models (e.g. OLS & Poisson, or other).
To improve readability I would, therefore, like to name the models simply as such, e.g.

```
names(models) <- c("OLS", "Poisson", "OLS", "Poisson", ...)
```

instead of

```
names(models) <- c("OLS 1", "Poisson 1", "OLS 2", "Poisson 2", ...)
```

However, `modelsummary()` somehow does not permit the regressions to be named the same, resulting in the following errors:

```
Error: Can't bind data because some arguments have the same name
Backtrace:
  1. modelsummary::msummary(...)
  2. modelsummary::extract(...)
 10. dplyr::mutate(., group = "gof")
 12. dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, ...)
 13. DataMask$new(.data, caller_env())
 14. .subset2(public_bind_env, "initialize")(...)
 17. rlang::env_bind_lazy(...)
 18. rlang:::env_bind_impl(.env, exprs, "env_bind_lazy()", TRUE, binder)
```

and

```
 Error in htmlTable_add_header_above(kable_input, header, bold, italic,  : 
 The new header row you provided has a different total number of columns with the original `kabel()` output.
```

### MWE:

```
library(modelsummary)
library(kableExtra)

url <- 'https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/HistData/Guerry.csv'
dat <- read.csv(url)

models <- list()
models[['OLS']] <- lm(Crime_prop ~ Literacy, data = dat)
models[['Poisson']] <- glm(Crime_prop ~ Literacy + Clergy, family = poisson, data = dat)
models[['OLS']] <- lm(Crime_pers ~ Literacy, data = dat)
models[['Poisson']] <- glm(Crime_pers ~ Literacy + Clergy, family = poisson, data = dat)

# build table with `modelsummary` 
cm <- c( '(Intercept)' = 'Constant', 'Literacy' = 'Literacy (%)', 'Clergy' = 'Priests/capita')
cap <- 'A modelsummary table customized with kableExtra'

tab <- msummary(models, output = 'kableExtra',
                coef_map = cm, stars = TRUE,
                title = cap, gof_omit = 'IC|Log|Adj')

# customize table with `kableExtra`
tab %>%
  
  # column labels
  add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "Crimes (property)" = 2, "Crimes (person)" = 2))
```

### AddOn:

One workaround is to add a space `" "` to the model name, prior to building the table with `modelsummary`:

```
names(models) <- c("OLS", "Poisson", "OLS ", "Poisson ", ...)
```

Manually this is easily feasible for few model specifications and variable combinations.
However, a solution that could dynamically adapt to the given settings would be preferred, i.e. to suit also cases as the following:

```
names(models) <- c("OLS", "Poisson", "GLM", "Poisson", ...)
```

instead of

```
names(models) <- c("OLS 1", "Poisson 1", "GLM 2", "Poisson 2", ...)
```

### UPDATE:

With the updated package version made available by @Vincent, regression tables with models of the same name can easily be implemented also for models stored in nested lists, e.g. if they are added to sublists in a loop or via lapply(..., FUN).

```
models <- NA
models <- list()
models[["a"]][["OLS"]] <- lm(Crime_prop ~ Literacy, data = dat)
models[["a"]][["Poisson"]] <- glm(Crime_prop ~ Literacy + Clergy, family = poisson, data = dat)
models[["b"]][["OLS"]] <- lm(Crime_pers ~ Literacy, data = dat)
models[["b"]][["Poisson"]] <- glm(Crime_pers ~ Literacy + Clergy, family = poisson, data = day)
# ...

models_unlisted <- unlist(models, recursive=FALSE)
names(models_unlisted) <- c('ols', 'poisson', 'ols', 'poisson')

cm <- c( '(Intercept)' = 'Constant', 'Literacy' = 'Literacy (%)', 'Clergy' = 'Priests/capita')

msummary(models_unlisted, output = 'kableExtra', statistic_vertical = FALSE,
         coef_map = cm, stars = TRUE, gof_omit = 'IC|Log|Adj') %>%
  add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "Crimes (property)" = 2, "Crimes (person)" = 2))
```

[image: modelsummary regression table output]

Comment: So I think you could keep the original model names for `msummary` and then `add_column`/`mutate` your `tab' data frame to create the required labels before `kable`ing it.  You could also drop the (now unwanted) original model names at the same time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the question. The other poster is right: your solution under MWE will never work because it relates to a fundamental feature of the `R` language. Assigning to the same name in a list overwrites the previous value. See:

```
a <- list()
a['blah'] <- 1
a['blah'] <- 2
a
```

The easiest trick I know is the one already proposed: add a space after names. This has one main disadvantage: it makes it harder to use select columns by names to customize them with `gt` or `kableExtra`. But aside from that it is quite innocuous, since all table-making packages strip out the white space before displaying the table.

After reading your question, I added a line of code to `modelsummary` to "pad" model names automatically. If you install from Github (I'll release to CRAN soon), you should be able to run this:

```
library(remotes)
install_github('vincentarelbundock/modelsummary')

library(modelsummary)
library(kableExtra)

url <- 'https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/HistData/Guerry.csv'
dat <- read.csv(url)

models <- list()
models[[1]] <- lm(Crime_prop ~ Literacy, data = dat)
models[[2]] <- glm(Crime_prop ~ Literacy + Clergy, family = poisson, data = dat)
models[[3]] <- lm(Crime_pers ~ Literacy, data = dat)
models[[4]] <- glm(Crime_pers ~ Literacy + Clergy, family = poisson, data = dat)
names(models) <- c('ols', 'poisson', 'ols', 'poisson')

cm <- c( '(Intercept)' = 'Constant', 'Literacy' = 'Literacy (%)', 'Clergy' = 'Priests/capita')
cap <- 'A modelsummary table customized with kableExtra'

msummary(models, output = 'kableExtra',
         coef_map = cm, stars = TRUE,
         title = cap, gof_omit = 'IC|Log|Adj') %>%
       add_header_above(c(" " = 1, "Crimes (property)" = 2, "Crimes (person)" = 2))
```

PS: please open an issue on Github if you have feature requests: https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/modelsummary/issues

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response! I installed the latest version from GitHub and tried your updated MWE. However, I still received (pretty much) the above error `Error: Can't bind data because some arguments have the same name
Backtrace: 1. %>%(...) 4. modelsummary::msummary(...)` with `1. %>% (...)` appearing since the update.

Comment: Did you try restarting your R session? And clearing the workspace.

Comment: indeed I did, but that did not help. Now rebooting and rerunning `install_github('vincentarelbundock/modelsummary')` everything works like charm! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

At the moment the 3rd and 4th models in your MWE overwrite the first two so there are only two elements in the `models` list, which then gives you the `different total number of columns` error.

If it is just readability you are after you could add a space after the name in the 3rd and 4th model and the rest should display nicely.

```
models[['OLS ']] <- lm(Crime_pers ~ Literacy, data = dat)
models[['Poisson ']] <- glm(Crime_pers ~ Literacy + Clergy, family = poisson, data = dat)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Chris. That is a workaround I already applied when there are only two model specifications and variable combinations. However, if there are more of each and especially if they are generated dynamically, this workaround has its limits.

Comment: Ah ok - you could probably add a space in the dynamically generated names as well - if you add that part to the MWE maybe someone could help.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, just added the details to the question.